# Error al crear efecto con css

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Quiero realizar el siguiente diseño con css, pero no me funciona.
Este es mi código.

```css
.card-face-path {
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#BA68C8, #BA68C8 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 6px);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(#BA68C8, #BA68C8 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 6px);
    border-color: #BA68C8;
}
.card-face-path {
    position: absolute;
    left: 105px;
    top: 36px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-face-path"></div>
```

El resultado que deseo obtener es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin necesidad de añadir nuevos elementos en tu HTML, sólo cambiando el CSS, podrías usar `::before` y `::after` para dibujar los círculos y que la línea punteada sea el elemento en sí. Algo como esto:

```css
.card-face-path {
    position: absolute;
    left: 105px;
    top: 36px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 4px dotted #BA68C8;
}

.card-face-path::before, .card-face-path::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-11px;
  left:-11px;
  border:4px solid #BA68C8;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:white;
}

.card-face-path::after {
  top:auto;
  bottom:-11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-face-path"></div>
```

Comment: La principal contra con usar los psedoselectores before y after al **dibujar** es que rompen con OOCSS perdiendo flexibilidad. Sin embargo, para este caso en específico, esta solución es la mejor.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando se trata de hacer figuras usando CSS (ahora las posibilidades son demasiado amplias), es recomendable usar clases para representar un figura o parte de ella. Por ejemplo:

```css
.ball {
  border: 3px solid #BA68C8;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}

.lines {
  border: 3px dashed #BA68C8;
  margin: 35px 0 0 -23px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 60px;
}

.figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin: 50px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
}

.ball:last-of-type {
  margin: 35px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="lines"></div>
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: A diferencia de la respuesta de Álvaro, esta solución te permite escribir código [OOCSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/), que es un conjunto de prácticas para escribir CSS reusable. En dibujos pequeños como este, la solución de Álvaro puede ser simple y práctica, pero en casos complejos, no es recomendado. Tenlo en cuenta para futuros dibujos.